# Recommendation for Role Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, privileges

I have successfully gotten authlogic working with rails 3 on windows 7 x64. But I'm lost as for what I should use for managing user privileges any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: I would also recommend CanCan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of options for authorization. My favorites in order are:

- Declarative Auth: http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization
- Ryan Bates' cancan: http://github.com/ryanb/cancan
- ACL9: http://github.com/be9/acl9

Answer (score 0):

Cancan http://github.com/ryanb/cancan is flexible enough to be easily extended with roles as Martin Rehfeld did with https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model. I've used this combination so often I created a gem to make working with these two gems simple https://github.com/james2m/canard