# Dynamically add/modify activerecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have what I'd think would not be a unique situation with ActiveRecord, but I can't seem to find anyone with a similar issue, so here goes:

I have a User class for users and a Roles class that defines the capabilities of the user. For ex, you could have a user with a role of 'tutor', a user with a role of 'student', and a user with a role of ['tutor', 'student']:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

What I'd like to do is add activerecord associations based on roles. Clearly, a student may have many :courses, a tutor may have a :subject they teach, and both a student and tutor could have many :appointments, but it doesn't seem like adding all these associations to every User instance is the right way to go.

Subclassing User also seems wrong - I thought about doing Tutor < User and Student < User, and adding the proper associations in each subclass, but what if we have a student that is a tutor? Then we need a StudentTutor class? If more roles are added, this route seems dangerous.

I've considered doing something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  protected

  after_initialize do
    if self.has_role?(Role::STUDENT)
      has_many :courses # This does not work
    else
      # etc etc etc
    end
  end
end
```

But I have no idea if this is considered wrong or how I'd even make it work. What's the best method for dealing with this kind of user/role setup with associations?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a gem for your issue. See a related SO question: [Recommendation for Role Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264110/recommendation-for-role-gem)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure that these solve my issue. I may just be manufacturing the issue, however. My concern is that the User model will have a lot of associations, some of which may not relate to the current user instance - and maybe that's just OK?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Tutor < Role
  has_one :subject
end

class Student < Role
  has_many :courses
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure this works? I want to, for a user instance, be able to go user.courses if the user has a student role, and user.subject if the user has a tutor role. other tables, like courses, are mapped with a user_id, not a role_id...I suppose I could work out mapping with user_role, then go user.roles.tutor.something, but that seems hacky. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think this is the best approach that meets "users having multiple roles" requirement.